# Celery executor in airflow without Backend

Tags: celery, airflow

When running airflow in a single node, can I configure the celeryexecutor without a Celery Backend (redis, rabbitmq, zookeeper) etc.

Currently, since there is no backend infrastcucture available, running webserver and scheduler in single node (Localexecutor)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can I configure the celeryexecutor without a Celery Backend (redis, rabbitmq, zookeeper) etc when you are running in a single node (webserver and scheduler).